# Why can't I declare a MemoryStream nullable (MemoryStream?) when a function can return MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, nullable, memorystream

I have a function that returns `MemoryStream?`. So null if there was an error that occurred. Then I found that I cannot declare a variable `MemoryStream?`

```
public MemoryStream? GetResponseStream() { }
MemoryStream? stream = GetResponseStream();
```

> The type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) is a reference type (declared with the `class` keyword)  and therefore already is nullable by itself. Only value types (declared with the `struct` keyword) are non-nullable and can be made nullable with `?`.

So your method should look like this:

```
public MemoryStream GetResponseStream() { ... }
```

and your method call like this:

```
MemoryStream stream = GetResponseStream();
if (stream == null) { ... }
```

BTW: You might want to consider using exceptions to signal that an error occurred in `GetResponseStream` rather than returning `null`.

Answer (score 1):

`MemoryStream` is a reference type so can be null. Only value types can be made into `Nullable<T>` because they are not allowed to be assigned a null value otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Only value types can be nullable, not reference types. A `MemoryStream` can already be null, so it doesn't make sense to make it nullable

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `?` as reference types can be `null`.

```
public MemoryStream GetResponseStream()
{
    return(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The nullable modifier (?) is for use only with value types. A stream is an object type, which can always be set to null ( it is. by its nature, already 'nullable'). So there is no need to o what you are trying to do.